# How to configure connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, connect-mongo

I am using "connect-mongo" node module to store session data in mongodb.

Below is my code related to configuring connect-mongo

```
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
const session = require('express-session');
const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(session({
secret: "test",
store: new mongoStore({
  url: mongodbURL,
  collection : 'sessions',
  autoRemove: 'interval',
  autoRemoveInterval: 1 // In minutes. Default
}
}));
```

Once a user connects to root "/" url from browser, a record is getting inserted
in database

```
 {
"_id": "EZ2sy6jHvnrlsyofqCrKVfPtp6hv5FX_",
"session": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"name\":\"mongosession\"}",
"expires": ISODate("2016-06-14T15:19:15.548Z")
 }
```

My questions are

1. why is that originalMaxAge , expires keys of "session" are null and
   what needs to be modified so that these keys have a value.?
2. Since I have set autoRemoveInterval to 1 min , I was assuming that session
   values from database will be removed in 1 min , but that was not the case
   What needs to be modified to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Configure the [`cookie`](https://github.com/expressjs/session#cookie-options) property of `connect-session`. By default, `maxAge` is `null`, making the cookie a (browser-)session cookie.
2. Set the [`ttl`](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#session-expiration) property of `connect-mongo`, which defaults to 14 days (which looks about right, judging by the timestamp in the `expires` property). `autoRemoveInterval` only configures how often `connect-mongo` should check if there are any sessions that should expire.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Now I have added  ttl: 60 key/value ,and because autoRemoveInterval is 1 , i was expecting that if a given session is idle  for more than 1 min , then the session record in database will be removed , but the records is not being removed.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode what does the `expires` property of those documents show?

Comment: {
 "_id": "1234",
 "session": "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"secure\":false,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"name\":\"mongosession\"}",
 "expires": ISODate("2016-06-01T08:25:20.981Z")
}

Comment: Not sure, it looks like the expiration timestamp is valid, I don't know why `connect-mongo` isn't removing it from the database.